# Microsoft Visio - automatically refreshed org chart

Tags: excel, vba, visio

I would like to create automatic connection between Excel that contains organizational structure data and Visio that creates organizational chart. My goal is to make Visio to reflects all changes in excel file, such as: changing positions, adding or removing employees.

I tried option with linking data to shapes but it is not what I want - it does not reflect changes in structure. It only refreshes data about existing employees.

Additionally, I designed chart in Visio that is readable (organization have over 10k employees). It generated a lot of manual work to make this visually appealing. I would like to have refreshing solution that would not break my existing design - just to replace/add/remove data from excel file.

Is there any existing solution to make this happen? I googled a lot but found nothing what works.

I will be grateful for help. Myabe you had similar problem in your organization?

Answer (score 1):

Visio will not do what you want. The Visio offering is good for what it does but it is a one-size-fits-all solution.